# About hugo building blog,I could run locally,but in github,it could not load first.md

Tags: github, hugo

I have loaded themes correctly,when use ***hugo server --buildDrafts*** to browse localhost:1313 normally,but when use ***hugo server*** ,localhost:1313 could not load first.md(for example),so when I use **hugo** to create public folder and push it to github,it could not load .md ,too

here are images to show difference
[image: this is using **hugo server**]

[image: this is using **hugo server --buildDrafts**]

Comment: I don't see how GitHub (a remote repository) has anything to do with your local build.

Comment: In github,it is same as the first image,so I guess drafts not saved.If you want to see in github,you can browse http://jingyihiter.github.io/   .Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I find my error,In .md folder, 'draft = true'  is wrong,so the drafts are not saved.thanks

Comment: @JingYi would you like to close the question as solved, people might come here thinking it's still unanswered :)